# Keras TimeDistributed Not Masking CNN Model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

For the sake of example, I have an input consisting of 2 images,of total shape (2,299,299,3). I'm trying to apply inceptionv3 on each image, and then subsequently process the output with an LSTM. I'm using a masking layer to exclude a blank image from being processed (specified below).

The code is:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, \
Input, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Masking,TimeDistributed, LSTM,Dense,Flatten,Reshape,Lambda, Concatenate
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.applications import inception_v3

IMG_SIZE=(299,299,3)
def create_base():
    base_model = inception_v3.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
    base_model=Model(base_model.input,x)
    return base_model


base_model=create_base()

#Image mask to ignore images with pixel values of -1
IMAGE_MASK = -2*np.expand_dims(np.ones(IMG_SIZE),0)

final_input=Input((2,IMG_SIZE[0],IMG_SIZE[1],IMG_SIZE[2]))

final_model = Masking(mask_value = -2.)(final_input)
final_model = TimeDistributed(base_model)(final_model)
final_model = Lambda(lambda x: x, output_shape=lambda s:s)(final_model)
#final_model = Reshape(target_shape=(2, 2048))(final_model)
#final_model = Masking(mask_value = 0.)(final_model)
final_model = LSTM(5,return_sequences=False)(final_model)
final_model = Model(final_input,final_model)


#Create a sample test image
TEST_IMAGE = np.ones(IMG_SIZE)

#Create a test sample input, consisting of a normal image and a masked image
TEST_SAMPLE = np.concatenate((np.expand_dims(TEST_IMAGE,axis=0),IMAGE_MASK))



inp = final_model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in final_model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functors = [K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]
layer_outs = [func([np.expand_dims(TEST_SAMPLE,0), 1.]) for func in functors]
```

This does not work correctly. Specifically, the model should mask the IMAGE_MASK part of the input, but it instead processes it with inception (giving a nonzero output). here are the details:

layer_out[-1] , the LSTM output is fine:

`[array([[-0.15324114, -0.09620268, -0.01668587,  0.07938149, -0.00757846]], dtype=float32)]`

layer_out[-2] and layer_out[-3] , the LSTM input is *wrong*, it should have all zeros in the second array:

`[array([[[ 0.37713543,  0.36381325,  0.36197218, ...,  0.23298527,
           0.43247852,  0.34844452],
         [ 0.24972123,  0.2378867 ,  0.11810347, ...,  0.51930511,
           0.33289322,  0.33403745]]], dtype=float32)]`

layer_out[-4], the input to the CNN is correctly masked:

```
[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
           ..., 
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]],


         [[[-0., -0., -0.],
           [-0., -0., -0.],
           [-0., -0., -0.],
           ..., 
           [-0., -0., -0.],
           [-0., -0., -0.],
           [-0., -0., -0.]],
```

Note that the code seems to work **correctly** with a simpler base_model such as:

```py
def create_base():
    input_layer=Input(IMG_SIZE)
    base_model=Flatten()(input_layer)
    base_model=Dense(2048)(base_model)
    base_model=Model(input_layer,base_model)
    return base_model
```

I have exhausted most online resources on this. Permutations of this question have been asked on Keras's github, such as [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5533), [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9788) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5934#issuecomment-288811716), but I can't seem to find any concrete resolution.

The links suggest that the issues seem to be stemming from a combination of TimeDistributed being applied to BatchNormalization, and the hacky fixes of either the Lambda identity layer, or Reshape layers remove errors but don't seem to output the correct model.

I've tried to force the base model to support masking via:

```py
base_model.__setattr__('supports_masking',True)
```

and I've also tried applying an identity layer via:

```py
TimeDistributed(Lambda(lambda x: base_model(x), output_shape=lambda s:s))(final_model)
```

but none of these seem to work. Note that I would like the final model to be trainable, in particular the CNN part of it should remain trainable.

Comment: Have you checked that the generated result isn't a copy of the previous step?

Comment: You have two Masking layers, is that correct? I think you should have only the first. (I don't know if the second one makes the first ineffective)

Comment: You're also using a `Reshape` layer in the outer model, and as it seems from the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L765), Reshape layers don't have `supports_masking=True`. -- Maybe you should `TimeDistributed(Reshape((2048,))`?

Comment: The lambda layer in your code does nothing.

Comment: After checking all this, if it works, let me know so I can post the correct cause as an answer.

Comment: @DanielMöller: Thank's a ton for the suggestions. I'll try to implement them and write back. From the link here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5533#issuecomment-289366176

They were using a similar reshape call to me. That's part of why I'm so confused by all this.

To answer your double masking question, so the first masking layer ensures that the CNN outputs all 0s on the masked inputs. The second masking layer is supposed to tell the LSTM to not process the 0 inputs.

Comment: Are you sure you need double masking? I really believe masking layers repeat the previous step, so it will not be zeros.

Comment: Also, one masking layer should be enough for the entire model. See: https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking ("...then the timestep will be masked (skipped) **in all downstream layers**")

Comment: @DanielMöller: The Reshape was likely spurious on my part. I also removed the second masking layer. Unfortunately the problem persists. I really think this has something to do with the way TimeDistributed is acting on the model, because the simpler model works fine.

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Have you checked if the results in step 2 are exactly equal to step 1? (This is a common output when masking is used).

Comment: @DanielMöller: I've taken out the reshape and masking layers, and posted outputs of the relevant layers. I really think this is an issue with combining TimeDistributed on BatchNorm layers. The Lambda layer that's applied above was suggested in the third github link I provided, but it looks like it *doesn't* support masking.

Comment: If I take out the Lambda layer as well, I get "Dimension must be 4 but is 3 for 'lstm_14/transpose_1' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,2,299,299], [3].", which seems to imply the LSTM thinks its getting a single channel of the mask input, which makes zero sense.

Comment: You need a `TimeDistributed(Flatten())` before the LSTM.

Comment: @DanielMöller: That produces the same lstm error, if I exclude the Lambda layer as well. With the lambda layer, the non-masking issue remains. Actually now I'm even more confused. Does "[?,2,299,299], [3]" mean that it has split the input into 3 separate channels? Wouldn't that mean CNN is now getting a garbage input?

Comment: I came to the conclusion that `TimeDistributed` simply doesn't work correctly with masking. A mere `final_model = Masking(mask_value = -2.)(final_model)` + `final_model = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(final_model)` + `final_model = LSTM(5,return_sequences=False)(final_model)` brings the same error.

Comment: @DanielMöller: It still feels like it has something to do with the the complexity of the InceptionV3 model, because the example above with a basic model works exactly as it should, not predicting on the masked values.

Comment: I was able to find a lot of different ways of trying, all of them bringing a different error. But there is indeed something different, such as this very simple bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179794/keras-timedistributed-inceptionv3-bug

Comment: @DanielMöller: Does the same issue arise in versions of tensorflow > 1.4 and keras >2.1.0. That batch normalization issue was fixed i think : https://github.com/broadinstitute/keras-rcnn/issues/42

Comment: Can you test on your machine? If you don't get a bug with that, I probably have an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure this will work, but based on the [comment made here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179794/keras-timedistributed-inceptionv3-bug?noredirect=1#comment87440340_50179794), with a newer version of tensorflow + keras it should work:

```
final_model = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(final_input)
final_model = Masking(mask_value = -2.)(final_model)
final_model = TimeDistributed(Reshape(IMG_SIZE))(final_model)
final_model = TimeDistributed(base_model)(final_model)
final_model = Model(final_input,final_model)
```

I took a look at the source code of masking, and I noticed Keras creates a mask tensor that only reduces the last axis. As long as you're dealing with 5D tensors, it will cause no problem, but when you reduce the dimensions for the LSTM, this masking tensor becomes incompatible.

Doing the first flatten step, before masking, will assure that the masking tensor works properly for 3D tensors. Then you expand the image again to its original size.

---

I'll probably try to install newer versions soon to test it myself, but these installing procedures have caused too much trouble and I'm in the middle of something important here.

On my machine, this code compiles, but that strange error appears in prediction time (see link at the first line of this answer).

---

### Creating a model for predicting the intermediate layers

I'm not sure, by the code I've seen, that the masking function is kept internally in tensors. I don't know exactly how it works, but it seems to be managed separately from the building of the functions inside the layers.

So, try using a keras standard model to make the predictions:

```
inp = final_model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in final_model.layers]          # all layer outputs

fullModel = Model(inp,outputs)
layerPredictions = fullModel.predict(np.expand_dims(TEST_SAMPLE,0))

print(layerPredictions[-2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It looks like this runs with tensorflow>=1.6.0. However, the masking still seems to be an issue. I would expect the second-to-last layer of the model to produce zeros on the mask, but unfortunately it does not :(. ```layer_outs[-2]``` looks like: ```[array([[[0.3751105 , 0.3711231 , 0.35439733, ..., 0.18241584,
          0.4650436 , 0.37185603],
         [0.2428138 , 0.22842434, 0.13101618, ..., 0.53246826,
          0.325293  , 0.3244964 ]]], dtype=float32)]
``` whereas with Masking I would expect the second part of the output to be all 0s.

Comment: What is the final output?

Comment: Just in case, try using a standard keras model to make the predictions, such as in the code I added at the end.

Comment: Even with the keras layer predictions, layerPrediction[-1] still doesn't mask the second CNN output, e.g. ```array([[[4.0904386e-03, 2.4350915e-02, 1.8814564e-02, ...,
         7.7942890e-01, 3.1489376e-02, 2.6609477e-02],
        [1.0464169e-01, 9.1234492e-03, 1.1754781e-01, ...,
         4.9686256e-01, 3.3937139e-04, 1.3018469e-04]]], dtype=float32)```
should really be:
```array([[[4.0904386e-03, 2.4350915e-02, 1.8814564e-02, ...,
         7.7942890e-01, 3.1489376e-02, 2.6609477e-02],
        [0., 0., 0., ...,
         0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)```

Comment: Maybe I can try to manually check if the LSTM is actually predicting on the second masked input, although this doesn't fill me with confidence because who knows what's really wrong under-the-hood.

Comment: You can check if `(outputs[:,0] == outputs[:,1]).all()`, or `(outputs[:,1] == 0).all()`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be working as intended. Masking in Keras doesn't produce zeros as you would expect, it instead skips the timesteps that are masked in upstream layers such as LSTM and loss calculation. In case of RNNs, Keras (at least tensorflow) is implemented such that the states from the previous step are carried over, [tensorflow_backend.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ba6f4945858bdf02bf10fc833430fb77894693db/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2871). This is done in part to preserve the shapes of tensors when dynamic input is given.

If you really want zeros you will have to implement your own layer with a similar logic to Masking and return zeros explicitly. To solve your problem, you need a mask before the final LSTM layer using the `final_input`:

```
class MyMask(Masking):
   """Layer that adds a mask based on initial input."""
   def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
      # Might need to adjust shapes
      return K.any(K.not_equal(inputs[0], self.mask_value), axis=-1)

   def call(self, inputs):
      # We just return input back
      return inputs[1]

   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
     return input_shape[1]
final_model = MyMask(mask_value=-2.)([final_input, final_model])
```

You probably can attach the mask in a simpler manner but this custom class essentially adds a mask based on your initial inputs and outputs a Keras tensor that now has a mask.

Your LSTM will ignore in your example the second image. To confirm you can `return_sequences=True`and check that the output for 2 images are identical.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll definitely look into this. I think part of the problem is that the inception model still doesn't support masking by itself, so it sounds like what's happening is that inception still predicts on masked images, but the LSTM chooses to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying implement the same thing, I want my LSTM sequences to have variable sizes. However I can't even implement your original model. I obtain the following error: TypeError: Layer input_1 does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask: Tensor("time_distributed_1/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, 100, 100), dtype=bool) I'm using tensorflow 1.10 and keras 2.2.2

I solved the problem by adding a second input, a mask to specify which timesteps to take into account for the LSTM. That way the image sequence always has the same number of timesteps, the CNN always generates an output, but some of them are ignored for the LSTM input. However, the missing images need to be chosen carefully so that the batch normalization is not affected.

```
def LSTM_CNN(params):
resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling = 'avg')
input_layer = Input(shape=(params.numFrames, params.height, params.width, 3))
input_mask = Input(shape=(params.numFrames,1))
curr_layer = TimeDistributed(resnet)(input_layer)    
resnetOutput = Dropout(0.5)(curr_layer)
curr_layer = multiply([resnetOutput,input_mask])
cnn_output = curr_layer
curr_layer = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(curr_layer)
lstm_out = LSTM(256, dropout=0.5)(curr_layer)
output = Dense(output_dim=params.numClasses, activation='sigmoid')(lstm_out)
model = Model([input_layer, input_mask], output)
return model
```