# Keras: TimeDistributed + InceptionV3 bug

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm facing a very curious bug in Keras when trying to use Inception inside a TimeDistributed wrapper.

This code is simple and should work with many models or layers, but weirdly, `inception_v3` fails at prediction time:

```python
import numpy as np
from keras.applications import inception_v3
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model

imgShape = (299,299,3)
seqShape = (2,299,299,3)
incept = inception_v3.InceptionV3(weights=None, include_top=False)

inputs = Input(seqShape)
outputs = TimeDistributed(incept)(inputs)
model = Model(inputs,outputs)
```

Everything works perfectly until I try to predict something:

```python
pred = model.predict(np.ones((1,2,299,299,3)))
```

The error is:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool
>        [[Node: batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase = Placeholderdtype=DT_BOOL, shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Any solutions to this?

Using `Keras 2.1.0` and `Tensorflow 1.4.0`.

Comment: With `tensorflow 1.8.0` and `Keras 2.1.6` I ran your code without any errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... gotta update my packs .... (and hope no installing nightmares come to haunt me again...)